# How do I make multiple events happen by clicking the same button?

Tags: jquery

I have a div in my HTML file which I'm using as a button.

When I click on that button, I want my current image to disappear and another one to appear in its place. This I have working.

But then when I click that same button, I want that current image to fade out and a third image to fade in. When I try this all my images fade in at the same time and fade out at the same time and I cannot distinguish one from another.

How can I use the same button once I click it to fade out an image and fade in another image and so on?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <body>
    <div class="gameboy-button"></div>
  </body>
<html>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //This image automatically fades in when my page loads which I want...
  $('.gb1').fadeIn(3000).delay(500);

  //When you click this button gb1 fades out and gb2 fades in which is fine....
  $('.gameboy-button').click(function(){
    $('.gb1').fadeOut(500);
    $('.gb2').fadeIn(3000);
  });

  //When you click this same button again I want gb2 to fade out and gb3 to fade in
  $('.gameboy-button').click(function(){
    $('.gb2').fadeOut(500);
    $('.gb3').fadeIn(3000);
  });

});
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include a sample of the HTML you want this to work with?

Comment: Can you tell us the exact logic by which one or the other of the two click handlers should be firing for the same button?  Once you describe this, maybe someone can offer an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your code is adding two events to the click handler for the object. All of your code is executed before the button is ever pressed, so both things happen on every button press. To correct this, you can either change your click event after the button has been clicked:

```js
$('.gameboy-button').click(function(){
    $('.gb1').fadeToggle(500);
    $('.gb2').fadeToggle(3000);
    // during the first click event, un-bind this event
    $(this).unbind('click');
    // then bind a new click event for the next time you click it
    $(this).click(function(){
        $('.gb2').fadeOut(500);
        $('.gb3').fadeIn(3000);
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
      .gb2, .gb3{
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="gameboy-button">Click Me</button>
    <div class="gb1">I am GB One</div>
    <div class="gb2">I am GB Two</div>
    <div class="gb3">I am GB Three</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or make your code handle the current state a little more dynamically like this:

```js
var currentGb = 1
$('.gameboy-button').click(function(){
    $('.gb' + currentGb).fadeOut(500);
    nextGb = currentGb + 1;
    $('.gb' + nextGb).fadeIn(3000);
    currentGb = nextGb
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
      .gb2, .gb3{
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="gameboy-button">Click Me</button>
    <div class="gb1">I am GB One</div>
    <div class="gb2">I am GB Two</div>
    <div class="gb3">I am GB Three</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Simple and to the point. Thanks so much!

Comment: @thesubhuman If you fully test it and find that it is indeed what you are looking for, you will want to accept it as the answer.

Comment: Anthony, it would be helpful if you would edit your code snippets to include the jQuery library. As it is right now, your code errors out because "$ is not defined."

Comment: @BobRodes, I have edited as per your suggestion, so you can now see the working code in action!

Comment: Looks much nicer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to cycle the images...

But be cautious about the fade delays... It can lead to many concurring animations if you click too fast. That's why [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) is used here, to stop the current animation queue.

Then, if you have 3 images, what happens after 4 click?
You have to know how many images you have...
Then, the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) keeps the image numbering in range.

Last thing... You have to use the callback of the previous image fade out, to avoid having two images visible at the same time.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  //This image automatically fades in when my page loads which I want...
  $(".gb1").fadeIn(3000);
  
  var actualImg = 1;
  var ImgCount = $("[class^='gb']").length;
  
  //When you click this button gb1 fades out and gb2 fades in which is fine....
  $('.gameboy-button').click(function(){
    
    nextImg = (actualImg%ImgCount)+1;
    
    console.log(nextImg);
    
    $("[class^='gb']").stop().fadeOut(500, function(){
      $(".gb"+nextImg).stop().fadeIn(3000);
    });

    actualImg++;
  });

});
```

```css
.gameboy-button{
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius:6px;
  width:8em;
  text-align:center;
  padding:0.3em;
}
[class^='gb']{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="gameboy-button">Gameboy button</div>

<img class="gb1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=gb1">
<img class="gb2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=gb2">
<img class="gb3" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=gb3">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.gameboy-button').click(function(){
$('.gb1').fadeOut(500);
$('.gb2').fadeIn(3000);
$('.gameboy-button').off('click').click(function(){
$('.gb2').fadeOut(500);
$('.gb3').fadeIn(3000);
});
```

Comment: Please add more context. Just code as answer is not okay.

Comment: I agree, however it was already answered, when I wanted to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try this tried to grab all in function

```js
var index = 1;

function fadeInPic() {
  $('.gb1').fadeIn(3000).delay(500);
}

function fadeInPicByClick() {
  console.log($('.toggleDiv').length);
  var currentIndex = index;
  index++;
  if ($('.toggleDiv').length + 1 == index) {
    currentindex = $('.toggleDiv').length;
    index = 1;
  }
  $('.gb' + currentIndex).fadeOut(500);
  $('.gb' + index).fadeIn(3000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {

  //This image automatically fades in when my page loads which I want...

  fadeInPic();


  //When you click this button gb1 fades out and gb2 fades in which is fine....
  $('.gameboy-button').click(function() {
    fadeInPicByClick();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gameboy-button">button i guess</div>

<div class='gb1 toggleDiv' style='display:none'>
  gb1
</div>

<div class='gb2 toggleDiv' style='display:none'>
  gb2
</div>

<div class='gb3 toggleDiv' style='display:none'>
  gb3
</div>
```